# Eigenvector/value in linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this problem

> [image]

For (a), I wrote $$T(3x,4y) = \lambda (3x, 4y)$$

Since $T$ is a reflection, $\lambda = 1$

That is as far as I got

(b) I simply have no idea. I only know how to find $A$ through brute force.

Comment: Hint for b: If $K$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $A$ is similar to $K$, i.e. $A = P^{-1}KP$ for some matrix $P$. What are the columns of $P$?

Comment: Oh, it relates to diagonalization? No wonder I haven't had a clue. I've been using Axler, which doesn't mention about diagonalization until the very end. I am just trying out this problem to "relax". What about (a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the point $(4,3)$ is on the line, the reflection will take this point to itself; so this will be an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda =1$.
Similarly, the point $(3,-4)$ is on the line through the origin perpendicular to the given line; so the reflection will take $(3,-4)$ to its negative $(-3,4)$
and so $(-3,4)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda =-1$.

Comment: Oh right, the orthogonal component. I totally overlooked that one